# Why pywinauto cannot click on the next button?

Tags: pywinauto

I wrote an installation script, everything is working, but for the uninstall, pywinauto doesn't want to see the next button :

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto import Desktop

app = Application().start('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\softwareToUninstall\\Uninstall.exe')

uninstall = Desktop(backend='win32').window(title='Software Uninstall')
uninstall.Uninstall.click()

dlg = Desktop(backend='win32').window(title='Need confirmation to uninstall')
dlg.OK.click()

uninstall.Next.wait('ready', timeout=120)
uninstall.Next.click()

uninstall.Finish.click()
```

It's not working,I even try :

```
uninstall['&Next >'].wait('ready', timeout=120)
uninstall['&Next >'].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did a debug with :

```
for w in top_windows:
    print(w.window_text()+'.')
```

seems like my windows title contains space at this end, to have it working, I wrote :

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto import Desktop

import  pywinauto

app = Application().start('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\softwareToUninstall\\Uninstall.exe')


uninstall = Desktop(backend='win32').window(title='Software Uninstall')
uninstall.Uninstall.click()

dlg = Desktop(backend='win32').window(title='Need confirmation to uninstall')
dlg.OK.click()


uninstall = Desktop(backend='win32').window(title='Software Uninstall ')

uninstall.Next.wait('ready', timeout=120)
uninstall.Next.click()
uninstall.Finish.click()
```

I don't know why I cannot reuse the first call of Desktop(backend='win32').window(title='Software Uninstall') And I don't know why if I add the space in the first title, it's not finding the windows... So I have to do two calls...